# Best practice to use v-skeleton-loader with Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I want to make `v-skeleton-loder` loading when the data from API is not yet fetched. The thing is I use dispatch to call the action.

```
getSomething(id) {
 this.$store.dispatch("getSomething");
},
```

Here is my skeleton, and I also called the `loading` from Vuex using computed property.

```
<v-skeleton-loader type="table" :loading="loading"></v-skeleton-loader>
```

I put the loading in my store.js like this

```
state : {
loading:true}

actions: {
async getSomething(){
 await axios.get(url)
  .then(async () => {
      state.loading = false //after data is fetched
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
  })
 }
}
```

This doesn't work and I also don't know how to set the `loading` value back to true for other skeletons. Or is there any more efficient way to achieve this without using Vuex? Appreciate all help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set vuex state for loading:

```
const state = {
  loading: true,
};

const mutations = {
  changeLoadingState(state, loading) {
    state.loading = loading;
  },
},

const actions = {
  setLoadingState({ commit }, loading) {
    commit('changeLoadingState', loading);
  },
}
```

then dispatch action before and after

```
getSomething(id) {
  this.$store.dispatch("setLoadingState", true)
  this.$store.dispatch("getSomething");
  this.$store.dispatch("setLoadingState", false)
},
```

Comment: I think you made a typo, the function should be `setLoadingState`. I finally solved using your answer and combining it with watcher to see if the data is fetched. Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: @tara hey mate, you are right , I corrected the answer, you are welcome, cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't mutate state directly, it is done using mutations.I may have made mistakes in the code. Use it as a concept.

```
actions: {
async getSomething({commit}){
 commit('setLoading', true)
 axios.get(url)
  .then(() => {
      // do something with data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err)
  })
  .finally(() => {
     commit('setLoading', false)
   })
 }
}

mutations: {
setLoading(state, isLoading) {
state.loading=isLoading
}
}
```

Comment: oh yes, sorry my bad. but how/where do you set it back to `true` for other skeletons?

Comment: @tara I have edited the code like how I would have done. There is a good answer below too.